# MySQL partial matching in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, sql-like, mysql-5.7

I'm looking for operator that can wrap a SELECT expression that behave like LIKE operation (but instead of using it on WHERE clause, use it on SELECT expression) and will **return that expression**. Something that could operate like this:

```
SELECT LEFT(MutationGRCh37,1)
FROM mutationschema.cosmicmutations WHERE MutationGRCh37 LIKE '_:%'
```

But instead of using left and like, use some sort of composition of the two, like:

```
SELECT LIKE(MutationGRCh37,'_:%')
FROM mutationschema.cosmicmutations
```

This a simple example, but with more complex partial matching I need to use a lot of mathematical abstraction to handle this given just the string operations in here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Comment: What result set do you want back? MySQL will return a `1/0` for an expression like `SELECT (MutationGRCh37 LIKE '_:%')`

Comment: ...but I suspect what you're after is the pattern matched by `'_:%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get everything before the colon, you can use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(MutationGRCh37, ':', 1)
. . .
```

So, if the column contains `'abc:123'`, then this will return `'abc'`.

Comment: Can I do something so substring_index could handle empty expressions and not empty but without the ':' delimiter?

Comment: @fatsokol . . . If there is no `':'`, then `substring_index()` with an argument of `1` will return the entire string.  You can still use the `where` clause filter.